# Setting property value in Wix

Tags: wix

I am trying to set a property to the installation directory. The following code doesnt work

```
<SetProperty Id="TALKMANSERVICE_MESSAGESCONFIG" Before="InstallInitialize" Value="[INSTALLDIR]\services\MessagesConfig.xml" />
```

So when can I set this property to the installation directory that has been selected by the customer?

Answer (score 1):

Schedule it in the InstallExecuteSequence after CostFinalize.  This is needed because you are using the value [INSTALLDIR] which is a directory table entry ( assuming it exists in your MSI and isn't called something else like INSTALLLOCATION )  and this entry won't be resolved to a property until after file costing.

Also, why do you need this property?  You can use [#filekey] to have the installer tell you the full path to the file. See: [Formatted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> •If a substring of the form [#filekey] is found, it is replaced by the
>   full path of the file, with the value filekey used as a key into the
>   File table. The value of [#filekey] remains blank and is not replaced
>   by a path until the installer runs the CostInitialize action, FileCost
>   action, and CostFinalize action. The value of [#filekey] depends upon
>   the installation state of the component to which the file belongs. If
>   the component is run from the source, the value is the path to the
>   source location of the file. If the component is run locally, the
>   value is the path to the target location of the file after
>   installation. If the component has an action state of absent, the
>   installed state of the component is used to determine the [#filekey]
>   value. If the installed state of the component is also absent or null,
>   [#filekey] resolves to an empty string, otherwise it resolves to the
>   value based upon the component's installed state. For more information
>   about checking the installation state of components, see Checking the
>   Installation of Features, Components, Files.

Comment: I have tried CostFinalize as well but it doesnt work <SetProperty Id="TALKMANSERVICE_MESSAGESCONFIG" After="Costfinalize" Value="[INSTALLDIR]\services\MessagesConfig.xml" />. Even tried <SetProperty Id="TALKMANSERVICE_MESSAGESCONFIG" Before="InstallInitialize" Value="[INSTALLLOCATION]\services\MessagesConfig.xml" />

Comment: I need to save the installation location in a config file. Thats my target

Comment: Only SecureCustomProperties get passed from the UI to the Execute. Also during a silent installation the UI sequence isn't processed.  Try using the [#filekey] I pointed out to you. You shouldn't need this SetProperty in the first place.